# Complete directory names using the end of the string on command completition

Tags: zsh

Let's say I have a directory with the following contents:

```
/Project.Presentation
      /Project.Presentation.API
      /Project.Presentation.Web
      /Project.Presentation.Infra
      /Project.Presentation.Util
```

I want to do this **-> *Project.Presentation*: API**  and let it autocomplete to `Project.Presentation.API`. Inside `Project.Presentation` to type `API` and `<tab>`.

Is it possible to let zsh use this 'forgiving' way of ?

Answer (score 0):

You're overcomplicating your solution.

If you want to execute a command with a file inside these directories, or just `cd` in one of these directories.
Just write `cd` (or other command) first, then press `tab` that will complete `Project.Presentation.` then you can either write API or write A and press `tab`.

By the way, you can have a way to navigate through the possibilities with an extra tab key.

Read `man zshoptions` for to discover options available in zsh.

Comment: Yes but let's say there is also others but they don't contain `API`, then it would be nice if it's smart enough that i want the `Project.Presentation.API`.